# Sharepoint 2007 UserProfileService iterate CHOICE fields?

Tags: 2007, user-profile, web-services

Is there any way to view all available Choice fields for Sharepoint 2007 UserProfile Web Service?

Answer (score 1):

shoot me.  GetPropertyChoiceList()